# How to use 'b' prefix for variable (or that functionality)

Tags: python-3.x, byte, encode, octal

I have list of strings - or better 90% are literal stings
But sometimes there is also octal encoded string

aL = ['literalString, XYZ','Verri\303\250res-le-buisson, IDF']
I am retrieveing list items from input (json file)

I need to convert it to utf-8

This works as intended:

```
x = b'Verri\303\250res-le-buisson, IDF'
print(f'{type(x)}')
print(x.decode('utf-8'))

<class 'bytes'>
Verrières-le-buisson, IDF
```

The problem is that I cannot find the way to prefix (use functionality) of 'b' to variable.

As I would need:

```
b'x.decode('utf-8')
```

Converting variable to bytes does not work properly (like bytes(x,'utf-8')).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46650050/12479639

Comment: In short: `x = 'Verri\303\250res-le-buisson, IDF'` `print(x.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: @Axe319 thanks a lot, yes now I understand better and it works